# how to move an android view 20 dp up?

Tags: java, android, animation, dialog, android-animation

I want to move my view from bottom up

i need to support min API 8, and cannot add external lib

how would I do this if:

1) I want to move it 20 dps in 2 sec?

2) I want to move it from where it originally is till its top-left corner move twice as the view height?

here is my code:

```
  public static void slideTooltip(final LinearLayout toolTipLayout) {

    TranslateAnimation layoutTranslateAnimation =
        new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0F, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0F,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 2.0F, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0F);

    layoutTranslateAnimation.setDuration(10 * 1000);
    layoutTranslateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    layoutTranslateAnimation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

    final AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.2F, 1.0F);
    alphaAnimation.setDuration(10 * 1000);


    layoutTranslateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

      @Override
      public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        toolTipLayout.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }
    });

    toolTipLayout.startAnimation(layoutTranslateAnimation);
  }
```

but i see only small and quick view jump.
what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use the [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html):

```
// start 20 pixels down and with 0.2 alpha
toolTipLayout.setTranslationY(20);
toolTipLayout.setAlpha(0.2);
// animate up and to full alpha.
toolTipLayout.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1).setDuration(10*1000).start();
```

If you need to support Android devices pre API12, use the http://nineoldandroids.com wrapper lib.

Comment: i need to support min API 8, and cannot add external lib

Comment: I just found TranslateAnimations always more instable than ViewPropertyAnimations. Especially when you want to translate out of the parent bounds. Try just an alpha animation. Does that work better?

Comment: i need to support min API 8, and cannot add external lib